# Is there a better way to structure my mongoDB documents

Tags: mongodb

As you may see in my question history I am struggling to use MongoDB.  I have the following document structure.

[image: Document structure]

The value of t can be the same across many documents and the value of `vdata.d` will also repeat itself many times but never for the same value of `t`.

I have placed indexes on `t` and `vdata.d`.

The `t` value may be repeated in excess of 10,000 times and there are 355.9m documents in total.

I am really struggling to query the data. How do I query the data for a value of `t` for a given value of `vdata.d`.  I have the following and nothing is returned even though I know there is an entry for it.

```
db.TagValues.aggregate({$match: {t: "99CalcTrigger"}}, {$match: {"vdata.d: "2018-12-09T04:40:00Z"}
```

Also if I just query the data using:

```
db.TagValues.find({ "vdata":{"d": new Date ("2018-12-09T04:40:00Z")}})
```

Again nothing is returned and also the query is very very slow.

I have been reading the MongoDB documentation for hours but I am not making any progress.

Comment: "I have placed an index on t and vdata.d" - that is one compound index, correct? Not two individual indexes?

Comment: it is two separate indexes

Comment: If you really query the two fields together, then make one compound index.

Answer (score 1):

Use dot notation

```
db.TagValues.find({"t": ..., "vdata.d": ...})
```

> and also the query is very very slow

Of course, you're not passing `t` there, in addition to not using index on `vdata.d`. So mongod does full collection scan.